# Load an Orchard Module in another

Tags: orchardcms

I have two modules which one of them is dependent on the other.
When I go to my home page, the "slave module" is loaded nicely, but when I go to the "master module" (which is routed) I can't see the first one.

How do I show or force the rendering of the slave shape in the master module?

---

I don't know how to explain better, so I'll just tell the exactly scenario.

I create a module called "Store" (the master module) that implements a route to "/Store/{optional_parameters}".
When i navigate to this url, I get the expected result without problems.

BUT, i create another module called "Search" (the slave module) which is dependent on the Store module and needs to be displayed in every page (just like navigation and footer).
I thought I managed to do it, doing this in the Display override on SearchDriver:
    workContextAccessor.GetContext().Layout.Zones["Search"].Add(shape, "10");
Then if i navigate to "/"(or any route that isn't defined by me) i can see the search shape on the right spot, but if i navigate to "/Store" (or any route defined by me) i can't see anymore.
Btw, the StoreController has the "Theme" notation.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I edited the question to improve it. I hope I have been specific enough

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using a widget? That would just work and would be considerably less work. It would also be manageable without having to change code.